# Weird info/warning

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on MediaPlayer in android to play video. For all mobile, playing of video is working. But for a particular mobile it is not playing. The log showing "info/warning (860, 0)". When I looked at developers website, there is no mentioning of this warning. Can anyone please explain what is this warning about, because of which I'm not able to play video in particular mobile(Gionee).

Comment: This is probably because that particular phone does not have the codecs necessary to play the video.

Comment: @JonasCz: The format I'm playing is mp4. In mobile I can play mp4 videos.

Comment: There are various types of mp4 videos (Encoded with h.264 , webM,  etc...) Can you play that specific video in phone?